# Isomorphic object map in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying write a well-typed equivalent of lodash's `mapValues` which will have a return type with the same shape the original object, not just a `Record<x,y>`.

Given a source object:

```
const orig = {
  a: {
    get: () => "foo",
  },
  b: {
    get: () => 5,
  },
  c: {
    get: () => true,
  }
};
```

Then `mapValues(x => x.get(), orig)` would return

```
{
  a: "foo",
  b: 5,
  c: true,
}
```

And its type would be

```
{
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean
}
```

My first effort is generic on the respective values:

```
export const mapValues = <V1, V2>(
  f: (v: V1) => V2,
  obj: {[k: string]: V1},
): {[k: string]: V2} => {
  const result: {[k: string]: V2} = {};
  for (const k in obj) {
    result[k] = f(obj[k]);
  }
  return result;
};
```

But the type ends up being

```
{
    [k: string]: string | number | boolean;
}
```

My best effort so far (which doesn't compile) is:

```
export const mapValues2 = <TInput, TOutput>(
  f: <K extends keyof TInput>(v: TInput[K]) => (K extends keyof TOutput) ? TOutput[K] :never,
  obj: TInput,
): TOutput => {
  const result: Partial<TOutput> = {};
  for (const k in obj) {
    result[k] = f<typeof k>(obj[k]);
  }
  return result as TOutput;
};
```

[I have a playground here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUBYAUDnqB7SAZ2lAPnAHNQBeUAbx1FGQC5HmXQrZoOAFAEo6APlAAiRAQISANFwC%20C7CwBGHJqu69%20oYWNABWFS2VdUmri12CRtcdHgBXWKdCKcigNx5c-2AAPAAcKMkISMgBbZGCANWQAG1diOlAAHjiARjlQOIAmUQEuREEANw5s%203EC9wI1ACtNAG0Aaw5SSkgqAF1KrPNsIRb20E6oXsr8xUMtFgjSUHhYYmdEvQY2jqcJvrzptIYfEop9BbJWiEhyRpE57mXV9baetMQBeoaXoV9tT21ltBnPBro81tBfscAiEwqBzqAYvEkil8ml0gAVACSkGCzmguXRAHk8bjoEUShx0gBpUBBOCQAAmqVasAAngREKAsTi8UUKlzsaTmlSetV9DS6bBGcy2RyucToKSRAB%20eUkvHC15sSCwMoIdwgUClDISwL0pmgFnsznc0l8ji2jUisVE9VkSXSxigLagEUcZyQVqQAgAd2uM1VrsVTq1oB1evg7kCDsFeJUwzV0bIDk42nhYPWHAACsh4NBwEkMQq7YcoSxpPAzkRFpcoKBAndrEsVuCXm90tBWcFYHLWkVAt9fmYuIDgaCe%20tWKko6TIb98M2yGVkSs0oiEskVgIBB3DIEAHS6YS5CjUH6gQ0Mb2jcbdPavmgAHzjziiagQoDfmoMiJLAyCQN4Hh%20IaxAABYEGsDKgP%20XrsGMOzdLkGg-n%20%20pwhwwEEKB4FQdg8LboexCovQ%2047lRx6njmF5XkIN6UFQPxAA)

Comment: There is a fundamental limitation to what you're trying to do: you are mapping values at *runtime* which maybe different than the type of an object at *compile-time*. This is the same reason built-ins like `Object.keys` doesn't correspond to the type of the object you're reflecting on. If you're doing this for your own use and understand that limitation (i.e. that it isn't actually type-safe) cool, but there's a reason libraries don't. Otherwise use type-safe bespoke access.

Comment: It's possible if beforehand you know what operation you want to do (here it's getting the return type of `get`) like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBOBLA5jAvDA3gWAFAxgEMAuLPAg5AUylIAoBKdAPhgCIAzEENgGnJgBffvhgAjUjlGUa9JmlYBWEQWEDgkgTNoxGLGFHgBXKiqF5BAbjx4oATwAOVGAFlCDgOI0IAHgDyrBhSBADaANIwiGAwANZUdiAcMH4AuqR+4SkwVAAeUFRgACYQWDDUOnoKkWAcVPAwACpCMAD8jTCkYFQAbnXWuFY2uPZOMACiOQ6ERT4Nge25+UUlIGIAVlTAsG3BMOHVsfGJjWnjk9OFs5nM-YIdjf14hZsANoTwzhxGYFuI4DAAW3cADVCC8TL4AnQQOkGKQJlMZm5PN5-MwbkNQJBYN0wRD0ICQXiqBBoUhkAxLDA8EA)

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah,  I just keep thinking if the correctly-shaped type of the input is known there must be a way to get the corresponding output.

Comment: @kellys That's the one! Thank you. Edit - right, it's dependent on the actual operation. Well, that's good progress.

Comment: @N3dst4 I mean you *can* but it isn't actually safe unless the thing in question is a constant compile-time known value because the keys could have been deleted or more keys pointing at values with a different type(s) may have been added. So when using runtime reflection you *don't* actually know the shape of the input ahead of time at compilation (again, unless it's an immutable const).

Comment: Now sometimes we as the programmer know it's ok, and I am certainly not dogmatically opposed to fudging type safety in exchange for big wins in brevity, clarity, flexibility, etc, but the compiler is going to be necessarily conservative about sticking to things it can prove.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm certainly not looking to fudge safety - I was hoping TS would be able to express a safe way of doing this. So, the way I've ended up thinking about this is that if you take kelly's example, to make it generic, you would need the function type to be a type parameter, but it requires type parameters itself. This is what other languages call a high-kinded type, and TS does not havs those.

Comment: [You can fake them really well for a lot of uses](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts) by (ab)using interface extension, but you would also (per the logic above) need objects to be more-or-less immutable at runtime, and they aren't.

Comment: @JaredSmith Oh that's a good link, thanks. But yeah, you're right. I'll settle for a good old `as` :)